# Sorting arrays by order

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently starting to learn java for school and for myself and I am stuck on a question I can't answer...

The problem contains two arrays including different ints with different length. 
Both arrays should have the same order of numbers when they are included in the array.

For Examples {3,8,2,6}  and {3,2,6}

How can I make sure that the arrays are sorted in the same way? 
I don't want a sort method form lowest to highest, just the same order?

The algorithm should be based on normale if/ while/ for methods.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: "I don't want a sort method form lowest to highest, just the same order?" What does that mean? If they are both sorted from lowest to highest, they *will* be in the same order; but otherwise, what happens if something appears in one array but not the other? Or a different number of times in the two arrays?

Comment: Generally it's best if you give some idea of the stuff you've tried, what you have currently and what your personal findings are while experimenting. It helps us put it in a context that you understand better and also allows us to use your code for explanation

Answer (score 0):

I think a code like below should solve your need. Finally, c will have elements of b ordered same as a. Hope this helps you. Still I don't understand the use of this.

Regards, Srikanth Kondaveti

```
int a[] = { 3,8,2,6};
int b[] = {6,3,2};
int c[] = new int[b.length];

int index = 0;
for(int k=0; k<a.length; k++)   {
    for(int l=0; l<b.length; l++)   {
        if(a[k]==b[l])  {
            c[index++]=b[l];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```